# net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteException while opening database after resuming app

Tags: android, sqlite, sqlcipher

I'm getting the following error when using the encrypted [SQLCipher](http://sqlcipher.net/) database in my Android app, but only off and on:

```
net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteException: not an error
    at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.dbopen(Native Method)
    at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.<init>(SQLiteDatabase.java:1950)
    at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:900)
    at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:947)
    at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:195)
    at com.android.storage.DatabaseHelper.getReadable(DatabaseHelper.java:99)
    ...
```

I've got the proper files in the `assets/` and `libs/` folders because the database works fine most of the time. However, every once in awhile I'll see this error. I've seen this twice now on my phone and it's always been after resuming the app after hours of inactivity (I check for user's oauth token in db if it gets cleared from memory).

I call "SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs(this)" only from the Application::onCreate() method so my hunch is that this isn't getting called on a resume and is throwing the error. **Does this sound possible?** If so, where should I call loadLibs? A user could enter the app in any activity and I access the db if the token isn't in memory. I see my options as either calling loadLibs on each Activity::onCreate or calling it each time I attempt to open the db. **Would it cause any harm or performance issues if I called it multiple times like this?**

Comment: Is that an external library you are using for SQLiteDatabase? Because default import was android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

Comment: Yes, I'm using the encrypted [SQLCipher](http://sqlcipher.net/) database. I've updated the question to make this clear.

Comment: Really weird indeed. I had the same issue. I will try the suggested solution and hopefully will not have any performance impact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider moving the `SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs(this);` to your application subclass of `net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteOpenHelper`.  You can then pass the static instance of your `Application` subclass as its argument.  Something like the following might be an example:

```
public class SchemaManager extends net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteOpenHelper {

  private static SchemaManager instance;

  public static synchronized SchemaManager getInstance() {
    if(instance == null) {
      SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs(YourApplication.getInstance());
      instance = new SchemaManager(…)
    }
    return instance;
  }
}
```

With regard to the exception that was provided, the Java routine calls into a JNI layer that calls `sqlite3_open_v2`, setting the soft heap limit and setting the busy timeout.  I would suggest adding logging locally to verify you are passing a valid path and a non null passphrase when attempting to acquire the `SQLiteDatabase` instance when you get a crash.  Calling `SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs(this);` multiple times shouldn't cause a noticeable performance impact, much of what occurs are calls to `System.loadLibrary(…)` which get mapped into `Runtime.getRuntime().loadLibrary(…)`, once a dynamic library has been loaded, subsequent calls are ignored.

Comment: Since making this change I haven't seen the issue. Thanks Nick.

Comment: Hi Nick, we are still getting this issue even when we try to load the libraries in static. Almost same error (I can say identical since stack trace also same). The call getReadableDatabse() or getWritableDatabase() is being made from multiple threads, we tried adding "synchronize" to the getReadableDatabase() & getWritableDatabase() functions as well.